# Block iframe src change through inspect element?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

want to know how to prevent fetching of new data by changing the `<iframe> src value` in the webpage, through inspect element?

In web page we are showing videos, in `<iframe> element`. Videos will available to user after purchasing them. All videos are stored in [Vimeo](https://vimeo.com/home), and through Vimeo settings configured in such way that, it will be available only through our domain.

And the problem is,
When a user purchase the video he/she can access the `src` value of `<iframe>` and can share with others. And who ever has that url can just go our website and do **inspect element** and change `src` value of any `<iframe> element` in web page, video will be loaded without purchasing.

How to prevent this? Is there any way to make `<iframe>` to not load the content after page loads? Also if a user want can edit html and put `<iframe> element` with url. **Or is this not the correct approach to implement payed videos in webpage?**

I am totally stuck at this point.
Many Many Thanks for all your input.

## update:

- Can I use google drive for this option? Using google drive api I can dynamically give access to each user account.

Comment: if you can't at least embed the video directly in the page without an `iframe`, i don't see any way to prevent this. As soon as they have the embed src, you can easily get around it as you describe

Comment: you are saying with out using `iframe` there is way around it??!!!

Comment: Well if it was something like, i dunno, streaming from Vimeo via your server, it would at least be much harder, and you can put user authentication on the request. But it looks like Vimeo doesn't support anything other than `iframe` embed.

Comment: Updated the question: - Can I use google drive for this option? Using google drive api I can dynamically give access to each user account. That will workout right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to prevent this. I'm not sure you can even detect the change from the outside due to cross-origin security, unless Vimeo has an API through cross-window messaging which you could to check the video ID - in this case the best thing you could do is have the page periodically verify the video ID inside the frame.

But even then, for a slightly more advanced "hacker" this would be no problem whatsoever. One could even defeat this whole system just by creating a local webserver which servers an HTML file containing the desired IFrame and setting up an entry in the hosts file which points your domain to 127.0.0.1... Or just use the NoScript extension and disable whatever is checking the video ID on your end.

Bottom line, once you are sending the Vimeo URL over the ether, you lost control over it and that's it. There is nothing you can do about that other than having the video streamed from your own server instead of Vimeo, where you can implement your own access control systems, e.g. creating one-time tokens valid only for this specific user and time, after verifying they rightfully have access to the content.

Comment: So only thing I can do is to keep the video files in my server itself! Is there any other service provider much better than Vimeo where this problem is handled?

Comment: I think bottom line is, if you want to have a _real_ paid for video service, you have to pay for the infrastructure. If it's a sideline part of a business and not worth the investment, you'll have to put up with some people getting them for free.

Comment: Updated the question: - Can I use google drive for this option? Using google drive api I can dynamically give access to each user account. That will workout right?

Comment: @Rhumborl this is one of the major part of business actually, we need it.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you are trying to take a third party host and create authentication that does not exist.

It wont work all the time, but you could try to set up a setInterval timer that runs a few times a second, if the url changes to an unexpected value you could force the page to redirect to an unauthorized page.

If you go this route I would recommend initially loading the iframe element through javascript, not markup so if the user disables javascript they simply cant view any videos

```
window.setInterval(function(){
    var frame = document.getElementById("frame");
    if(frame.src  !== expectedSource){
        window.location.href = "unauthorized.html" // or something like that
    }
}, 300);

// load iframe
window.onload = function(){
   var frame = document.createElement("iframe");
   document.body.insertBefore(frame, container); // container implies an existin DOM element 
   frame.src = expectedSource; // you will need some way to get the expected source and load it
}
```

Comment: User can disable the script, then do inspect element and then edit html to have an iframe element with the src value. It will load then. Also as **CherryDT** said `creating a local webserver` will also screw up. As you said, I am also feeling like third-party wont be help full for this scenario.

Comment: Updated the question: - Can I use google drive for this option? Using google drive api I can dynamically give access to each user account. That will workout right?

Comment: Another way to defeat this is to change the `src` from inside the IFrame itself, then the outer page can't detect it (for security reasons, as mentioned in my answer). See this example: https://www.jsnippet.net/snippet/1031/

Comment: As I said, it wont work all the time.  I have found very few sites that host third party videos that I could not get to if I tried hard enough.  This will stop the basic knowledge user in most cases

Comment: ...as long as there is nobody creating a simple userscript or something like this or a "copy this into your console" trick and share it so it can be found easily by googling for "theVideoService watch video free" or such.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want someone to change your iframe's "src", you can make the "src" property 'writable: false', so third party won't be able to change that.

Example:

```
var element = document.getElementById('iframe');
Object.defineProperty(element, 'src', {
    writable: false
});
```

Also, someone can change `src` by calling `element.setAttribute('src', value)`, so you can prevent this by overriding the setAttribute method.

Example:

```
var set  = element.setAttribute;
element.setAttribute = function(attr, val) {
    //do whatever
    //set.call(this, attr, val);
};
```

Comment: In Chrome, you can still set the `src` attribute directly from the Elements panel.